# Syntax error on token for a "private static final"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I'm so sick of android errors in eclipse.. this has been happening for too long but here it goes.

here's the code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.R;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

//constants used when saving/restoring state

private static final String BILL_TOTAL = "BILL_TOTAL";
private static final String CUSTOM_PERCENT = "CUSTOM_PERCENT";
```

I just threw the imports in to see where the code starts

the first private static final (BILL_TOTAL) errors like this:

> > Multiple markers at this line
> >         - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
> >          construct(s)
> >         - Syntax error on tokens, delete these 
> >          tokens
> >         - Syntax error on tokens, delete these 
> >          tokens

I delete the first private static final then the error jumps to the next static method declaration... ugh.. the code is 90% done and I know there are no errors.. (if anything a curly brace somewhere)..

Please help me understand these random eclipse errors. 
thanks in advance

Also... in the midst of all this i lost access to my main layout

> > main cannot be resolved or is not a field

also one last thing

NONE of my variables "can be resolved as a variable"

Answer (score 5):

Those `private static final` variables need to be inside of a `class` context:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.R;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;


class MyClass {

    //constants used when saving/restoring state
    private static final String BILL_TOTAL = "BILL_TOTAL";
    private static final String CUSTOM_PERCENT = "CUSTOM_PERCENT";

    ...

}
```

Comment: simple enough Thanks... and my main issue was because of my import